# Find a pattern within a string and relace it with another string in swift

Tags: swift

There are no straight forward methods in swift to implement and execute regex.

I want to search for numbers within a string and replace it with another string. For ex:

```
var numberString = "I have 567 horses in my barn"
var replacementString = "many"
```

How do i search for the indices of existing number and relace them with my string so that it looks like:

```
var finalString = "i have many horses in my barn"
```

EDIT : The code should take in consideration of additional formatting on numbers. so that even strings like
var numberString = "I have 5,675.00 horses in my barn"  can be edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*There are* <strike>no</strike> *straight forward methods in swift to implement and execute regex.*

```
let numberString = "I have 567 horses in my barn"
let replacementString = "many"
let finalString = numberString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+", with: replacementString, options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: can the above code be modified so that it addresses scenarios where number has a formatting. 
For eg : It can be something like
let numberString = "I have 5,676.00 horses in my barn"

Comment: Dang, it can be so easy sometimes!

Comment: Is the  pattern `"[0-9.,]+"` sufficient?

Comment: You can test patterns at [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com). Just remember to add extra backslashes in your strings in Xcode.

Comment: @vadian: i think "[0-9.,]+" should cover it. This is a lifesaver. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
var numberString = "I have 567 horses in my barn"
var replacementString = "many"
if let range = numberString.range(of: "([0-9])+", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) {
    numberString.replaceSubrange(range, with: replacementString)
}
//Result: "I have many horses in my barn"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "I have 567 horses in my barn"

let decimalCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

let decimalRange = str.rangeOfCharacter(from: decimalCharacters)

if decimalRange != nil {
    print("Numbers found.. Replace this with the replacement string")
}
```

From the above usage, you can get the range of the number in the string. Then you can replace that string with your replacement string.